# What is difference between , (comma) and . (dot) as a concatenation operator?

Tags: php

Here is simple PHP code

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="calcbyme.php"></br>
    enter value1 :<input type="text" name="f1"></br>
    give operator :<input type="text" name="op"></br>
    enter value2 :<input type="text" name="f2"></br>
    <input type="submit" value="calculate"></br>';
    if(isset( $_POST["f1"]) && isset($_POST["f2"]) && isset($_POST["op"]) ){
        $a=$_POST["f1"];
        $b=$_POST["f2"];
        $op=$_POST["op"];
        switch ($op){
            case '+':
                echo "$a+$b=". $a+$b; break;
            case '-':
                echo  "$a-$b=". $a-$b; break;
            case '*':
                echo "$a*$b=". $a*$b; break;
            case '/';
                echo "$a/$b=". $a/$b; break;
            default:
                echo "invalid operator"; break;
        }
    }
```

If I assume `$a=4` and `$b=2`
but this give only value like this

```
6
2
8
2
```

If I put , (comma) instead of . (dot) then it gives correct output like this

```
4+2=6
4-2=2
4*2=8
4/2=2
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Just of of curiosity, try to enclose math operations into `()`, eg. `($a+$b)`

Comment: Aren't you just recreating already-built-in arithmetic operators?

Comment: Note that `echo` + `,` is not string concatenation and is slightly faster (because it avoids that overhead). `echo $a, $b` is more like `echo $a; echo $b`. But regarding your question, see the answers that talk about operator precedence.

Comment: @Vyktor ya it works if i put math operation into ()

Comment: @summea you are right but i am going through college years. So our professor just gave us to create calc as students are dealing with basics of PHP.

Comment: @virpara I was little wrong with my answer, I've fixed it, it's accurate now. btw: this is homework, right? Add `homework` tag to it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with php [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)...

<s>Expression containing `.` is executed before expressions containing `+`, therefor implicit brackets are:</s>

`.+-` are equal operators (there's no precedence applied on them) and they are executed sequentially from start to end, therefor implicit brackets are:

```
echo ("$a+$b=". $a)+$b
```

So if you want correct output you should use:

```
echo "$a+$b=". ($a+$b)
```

Empiric examples:

```
php > echo "foo" . 1 + 2;
// 2
php > echo "foo" . (1 + 2);
// foo3
php > echo 1 + 3 . 'foo';
// 4foo
```

And why is `,` working... Because coma separates function arguments and php sees this as:

```
echo( "$a+$b=", $a+$b);
```

And coma operator (`,`) is evaluated as last one.

Comment: `echo` is _not_ a function, but a language construct, thus `"$a+$b="` and `$a+$b` are _not_ function arguments. The reason, why it works anyway, is that `,` has a _special_ meaning with `echo` (its evaluated as `echo "$a+$b=";echo $a+$b;`).

Comment: the lexer has less overhead with comma seperated echoes. so it's kind of micro optimization

Comment: Interesting that nobody explained why the first case actually returned the correct results... Because it is basically by chance. For number operators PHP automatically converts a string to a number such that it reads the string until it finds the first non-number character and then converts this. This behaviour is I believe quite unique...

Answer (score 0):

The difference is, that `,` is not a concatenation operator, but lets start from the beginning

```
echo "$a+$b=". $a+$b;
```

with `$a=2` and `$b=4` is evaluated like

```
echo ("4+2=". 4)+2;
echo "4+2=4"+2;
echo ((int) "4+2=4")+2;
echo 4+2;
echo 6
```

The point is, that the comma `,` does not concatenate, but it lists expressions (at least for `echo`. The [manual](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence) just says "many uses"...), thus every expression is executed on its own.

```
echo "$a+$b=", $a+$b;
echo "$a+$b="; echo $a+$b;
echo "2+4=";echo 2+4;
```